# Autohotkey switch Ctrl Spce with Alt Space

Tags: key, autohotkey, remap

Im a Autohotkey nowbie, I would like to know how to switch "Ctrl Space" with "Alt Space", I mean keeping down Ctrl Space, all the time I keep down Alt Space, and release it only when I realse Alt Space. without interfering with any other mouse clicks movements. Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This switches both key pairs, if you don't want <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to also translate back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, just use the first two blocks.

```
$^Space::
Send, !{Space down}
return

$^Space up::
Send, !{Space up}
return

$!Space::
Send, ^{Space down}
return

$!Space up::
Send, ^{Space up}
return
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work properly, any other suggestions pls?